# What factors contribute to tightly fitting tyre

Tags: wheels, tyre-width

I recently purchased a 2021 Giant Propel Advanced Pro 0 road bike and it came with Giant’s SLR1 hookless wheelset. I have been having a pretty tough time replacing the tube after I have received a puncture (hard to get the tyre on and off the rim) on the side of the road. Even after replacing the tube, getting the tyre to seat properly remains to be an issue.

For the above reason I am planning on purchasing a new carbon wheelset, one that I can change the tube relatively easily in the case of a puncture. I was wondering what specs I should keep and eye on in order to avoid this issue I am currently having.

I used to have a hooked carbon rim and never had any issues with that so possibly it’s just the hookless and tubeless that’s the issue? Perhaps it’s the inner/outer rim width or inner rim depth? Im not entirely sure.

Comment: When and where were you trying to install the tire? If it was cold out side or in your garage, that can be tough. During cooler weather, I’ll let the wheels sit in the cold garage while I warm up the tire in the house. Seems to help.

Comment: Besides generally fitting advice, trying another set of [compatible](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/global/hookless-technology) tires could be worth a try before changing wheels. New wheels are quite the investment... if all else fails, going hooked seems to be a good idea because you don't have to deal with issues like fitting/blowoffs and reduced tire compatibility.

Comment: ... but I should warn you. There are definitely tire/wheel combinations out that are still hard to fit, I've had everything from being easy to mount with my thumbs to hard times with tire levers, even with clincher tires.